# MongoDB - Group by inner element

Tags: database, mongodb, go, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am explaining with a simple example see my MongoDB collection looks like this:

```
[

    {
        pid: erwer,
        qty: 3,
        LevelDetails: {
            level1: { userId: 1, amount: 10 },
            level2: { userId: 2, amount: 20 },
            level3: { userId: 3, amount: 13 },
        }
    },
    {
        pid: qwsdfg,
        qty: 1,
        LevelDetails: {
            level1: { userId: 1, amount: 10 },
            level2: { userId: 4, amount: 20 },
            level3: { userId: 3, amount: 13 },
        }
    },

]
```

From the collection, I need the sum of Level 1, Level 2, and Level 3 for each user.

The query result should look like this:

```
[

    { userId1: { TotalLevel1Amount: 20, TotalLevel2Amount: 0, TotalLevel3Amount: 0 } },

    { userId2: { TotalLevel1Amount: 0, TotalLevel2Amount: 20, TotalLevel3Amount: 0 } },

    { userId3: { TotalLevel1Amount: 0, TotalLevel2Amount: 0, TotalLevel3Amount: 26 } },

    { userId4: { TotalLevel1Amount: 0, TotalLevel2Amount: 20, TotalLevel3Amount: 0 } }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$set`: Add new field `_levelDetails` by converting `LevelDetails` to key-value pair.
2. `$unwind`: Deconstruct `_levelDetails` array.
3. `$group`: Group by `_levelDetails.v.userId` and `$sum` conditionally based on level (`_levelDetails.k`).
4. `$project`: Format displayed document.
5. `$sort` (Optional): Sort by `userID` ascending.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      _levelDetails: {
        $objectToArray: "$LevelDetails"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$_levelDetails"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_levelDetails.v.userId",
      "TotalLevel1Amount": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$_levelDetails.k",
                "level1"
              ]
            },
            "$_levelDetails.v.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "TotalLevel2Amount": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$_levelDetails.k",
                "level2"
              ]
            },
            "$_levelDetails.v.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "TotalLevel3Amount": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$_levelDetails.k",
                "level3"
              ]
            },
            "$_levelDetails.v.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      userId: "$_id",
      TotalLevel1Amount: 1,
      TotalLevel2Amount: 1,
      TotalLevel3Amount: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      userId: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8ayDKKq5QMN)

---

> To Key-Value Pair: `{ 'userId': { // Result } }`

Steps 1 to 3 are the same as the previous solution.

4. `$sort` (Optional): Sort by `_id` ascending.
5. `$project`: Display document with `array` field (with properties `k` and `v`).
6. `$replaceRoot`: Replace entire documents to key (`userId`) and value (result).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      _levelDetails: {
        $objectToArray: "$LevelDetails"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$_levelDetails"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_levelDetails.v.userId",
      "TotalLevel1Amount": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$_levelDetails.k",
                "level1"
              ]
            },
            "$_levelDetails.v.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "TotalLevel2Amount": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$_levelDetails.k",
                "level2"
              ]
            },
            "$_levelDetails.v.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "TotalLevel3Amount": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              "$eq": [
                "$_levelDetails.k",
                "level3"
              ]
            },
            "$_levelDetails.v.amount",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      array: [
        {
          k: {
            $toString: "$_id"
          },
          v: {
            TotalLevel1Amount: "$TotalLevel1Amount",
            TotalLevel2Amount: "$TotalLevel2Amount",
            TotalLevel3Amount: "$TotalLevel3Amount"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$array"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (To Key-Value Pair)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JmCJRWQr3_w)